# Changing a Boolean from false to true

Tags: java, oop, boolean

I am creating a booking app for college lessons. My Lessons objects contain a Boolean called booked which is set to false. Is there a way of dynamically changing the boolean to true once a lesson has been booked?

To provide a bit more detail. I am going to create a scanner input for the user. When the user confirms that they would like to book a lesson. Ideally I need to implement a method that changes the status of the lesson to show that has been booked . In this instance changing the booked boolean to true

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Lesson {

    public String lessonName;
    public String lessonDay;
    public String lessonDate;
    public String lessonTime;
    public String tutorName;
    public Boolean booked;

    public Lesson() {
    }

    public Lesson(String lessonName, String lessonDay, String lessonDate, String lessonTime, String tutorName, Boolean booked) {
        this.lessonName = lessonName;
        this.lessonDay = lessonDay;
        this.lessonDate = lessonDate;
        this.lessonTime = lessonTime;
        this.tutorName = tutorName;
        this.booked = booked;
    }

    public Lesson(String lessonDay, String lessonDate, String lessonTime, String tutorName, Boolean booked) {
    }

    public String getLessonName() {
        return lessonName;
    }

    public void setLessonName(String lessonName) {
        this.lessonName = lessonName;
    }

    public String getLessonDay() {
        return lessonDay;
    }

    public void setLessonDay(String lessonDay) {
        this.lessonDay = lessonDay;
    }

    public String getLessonDate() {
        return lessonDate;
    }

    public void setLessonDate(String lessonDate) {
        this.lessonDate = lessonDate;
    }

    public String getLessonTime() {
        return lessonTime;
    }

    public void setLessonTime(String lessonTime) {
        this.lessonTime = lessonTime;
    }

    public String getTutorName() {
        return tutorName;
    }

    public void setTutorName(String tutorName) {
        this.tutorName = tutorName;
    }

    public Boolean getBooked() {
        return booked;
    }

    public void setBooked(Boolean booked) {
        this.booked = booked;
    }
```

To add some more details.
Below is the method for booking a lesson. It displays the details of the lesson to the user.

I have used mathsJuly.get(0) to get the lesson at index 0 from the arrayList. The Lesson object contains a Boolean (booked) which is set to false. What is the best way to change this boolean to true when the lesson has been booked? Can I somehow incorporate this into the method below or would I need to create a separate method i.e. changeLessonStatus to change the boolean at this specific index?

```
 void makeBooking(ArrayList<Lesson> mathsJuly) { 

 Lesson m = mathsJuly.get(0); 
 { 
 System.out.println("Lesson: " + m.getLessonName()); 
 System.out.println("Day: " + m.getLessonDay()); 
 System.out.println("Date: " + m.getLessonDate()); 
 System.out.println("Time: " + m.getLessonTime()); 
 System.out.println("Tutor: " + m.getTutorName()); 
 System.out.println("----------------------------"); 
 }
```

Comment: You already have a `setBooked` method - why is that not sufficient? Could you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: This is the method for booking a lesson:

Comment: @KevinJervis Add details as edits to your Answer, not as Comment.

Comment: Thanks for heads up Basil. I have added some more detail to the question. Hopefully this will provide some clarity

Answer (score 2):

When you call `setBooked`, you need to give it true. Do you you mean that ?